# Menu fixo no parallax

Tags: html, css, menu, posicionamento, parallax

Galera, já fiz de tudo mas não consigo colocar um menu fixo neste código (feito pelo tekzzoom), ao inserir um item o background o sobrepõe, e o item não permanece fixo na tela. Alguém pode me ajudar de alguma maneira? (segue o código com o style dentro do index). Fico super agradecido desde já.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MCVE</title>
        <style>
            html{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    perspective: 1px;
    color: black;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 400%;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
}

#secao1{
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
}

#secao2{
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: translateZ(-0.9px) scale(2);
    z-index: -1;
    
}

#secao3{
    background-color: green;
    background-size: cover;
}

.slide{
    position: relative;
    padding: 25% 10%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, -7);
    transform-style: inherit;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <section id="secao1" class="slide">
        <h1>MCVE</h1>
        </section>
        
        <section id="secao2" class="slide">
            <p>Conteúdo 1</p>
        </section>
        
        <section id="secao3" class="slide">
            <p>Conteúdo 2</p>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jovem existem duas maneiras para fazer isso, a primeira é mais trabalhosa, mas é a que eu te indico por ser crossbrowser. A outra opção é com o `position:sticky` que não tem um bom suporte nos browsers ainda, porem demanda menos estilos no css.

Na opção com `position:absolute` vc precisa criar um elemento pai (usei o `<main>`)e colocar as `sections` dentro, dessa forma vc pode retirar o `overflow-y:scroll` do `body` e colocar no `<main>` com as `sections` dentro. Depois disso vc precisa fazer um ajuste para corrigir a altura. Para isso vc tem que usar um `margin-top:` e `height:calc()`. Veja o exemplo abaixo.

```css
 html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 1px;
    color: black;
}
main {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    perspective: 1px;
    color: black;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 400%;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
}

#secao1 {
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/1000/1000);
}

#secao2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: translateZ(-0.9px) scale(2);
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/1000/1000);
}

#secao3 {
    background-color: green;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/1000/1000);
}

.slide {
    position: relative;
    padding: 25% 10%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, -7);
    transform-style: inherit;
}

nav {
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<nav>MENU</nav>

    <main>
    <section id="secao1" class="slide">
        <h1>MCVE</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="secao2" class="slide">
        <p>Conteúdo 1</p>
    </section>

    <section id="secao3" class="slide">
        <p>Conteúdo 2</p>
    </section>
    </main>
```

**Segunda opção**

A outra opção é com o `position:sticky`. Com ele vc não precisa usar o  por fora das `sections`, e pode deixar o `overflow-y:scroll` no `body` mesmo, e tb não precisa fazer os ajustes de altura. Porem ele não tem bom suporte nos browsers ainda. Veja abaixo o exemplo.
**Fonte:** https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    perspective: 1px;
    color: black;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    perspective: 1px;
    color: black;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 400%;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
}

#secao1 {
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/1000/1000);
}

#secao2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: translateZ(-0.9px) scale(2);
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/1000/1000);
}

#secao3 {
    background-color: green;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/1000/1000);
}

.slide {
    position: relative;
    padding: 25% 10%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, -7);
    transform-style: inherit;
}
nav {
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<nav>MENU</nav>

  <section id="secao1" class="slide">
      <h1>MCVE</h1>
  </section>

  <section id="secao2" class="slide">
      <p>Conteúdo 1</p>
  </section>

  <section id="secao3" class="slide">
      <p>Conteúdo 2</p>
  </section>
```