# Parallax com duas camadas ao rolar o mouse

Tags: html, css3, parallax

Estou tentando fazer um parallax em duas camadas e não estou conseguindo.

O que quero fazer é parecido ao site https://willianjusten.com.br/exemplos-de-sites-com-parallax/. Quero que a imagem de fundo e o título se deslocam para baixo ao mesmo tempo e em velocidade diferentes para dar a impressão de que a imagem está mais ao fundo e o título um pouco mais a frente ao rolar o mouse para baixo, e o efeito inverso ao rolar o mouse para cima.

O meu problema é que não faço a mínima idéia de como fazer em CSS3.

Já tentei vários exemplos como o do site:
https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/ mas sem o efeito desejado.

A estrutura do HTML para receber o parallax está assim:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row parallax">
  <div class="col">
    <h1 class="text-center">text here</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- restante do post -->
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

E o **CSS:**

```
.parallax{
   background:url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/23/22/12/orange-3036097_960_720.jpg');
   height:300px;
}
```

Comment: Brunão, mas lá no link que vc citou ele já ensina tudo... Aqui nessa resposta mesmo eu usei um modelo desses de Parallax com CSS onde o cara queria um menu fíxo no topo... Mas o código do parallax está lá é só testar ou pegar se te interessar  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235915/menu-fixo-no-parallax/259049#259049

Comment: Então acho que meu navegador está com problemas (Mozilla Linux) porque olha como está o seu exemplo do outro post: https://ibb.co/kHWxHK. O mesmo acontece com as tentativas de fazer o parallax. Sempre algo "buga"

Comment: Cara vc tem que verificar se essas propriedades precisam de prefixo. Pega todo aquele código CSS da outra resposta e cola aqui do lado da esquerda onde está escrito .exemple: https://autoprefixer.github.io/ ai o ferramente vai colocar os prefixos de todos os browses. Mas mesmo assim pode não funcionar, ai vc pode verificar aqui qual propriedade seu browser não aceita https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d só digitar no topo a propriedade que quer pesquisar